# Azure Firewall - Shared between prod and non-prod or separate per environment?

Tags: azure, firewall

According to the Microsoft's diagram in the [Hub-spoke network topology in Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/hybrid-networking/hub-spoke?tabs=cli) article, Hub network and Azure Firewall are shared between production and non-production spoke virtual networks.

[image]

Historically, I have separated prod with non-prod resources. It is not clear to me why I would not do that for a Firewall, aside for cost.

Assuming there is no cost factor for Azure Firewall, is there a reason why I would not want to follow the design in the article and have a separate Hub/Firewall per environment?

Thank you

Comment: Based on the information provided in the Azure Firewall Manager documentation, there is no technical reason why you cannot have separate Hub/Firewall per environment. However, it is important to note that having a shared Hub/Firewall between production and non-production environments can simplify management and reduce overall cost. It is ultimately up to your organization to decide which approach is best for your security requirements and budget.

Comment: References:

-   [What are the Azure Firewall Manager architecture options?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall-manager/vhubs-and-vnets#what-are-the-azure-firewall-manager-architecture-options)
-   [Hub-and-spoke network topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/hub-spoke-network-topology#overview)
-   [Azure DDoS Protection reference architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-reference-architectures#hub-and-spoke-network-topology-with-azure-firewall-and-azure-bastion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no strict technical constraints that prevent you from having separate Azure Firewall instances for each environment (production and non-production). Here are the main points to consider-
*If you have a Shared Firewall*

- Simplified management with a centralized set of rules.
- Cost savings as you are running and managing fewer resources.
- Potentially easier to apply a consistent security posture across all environments.

*If you have a Separate Firewall*

- Enhanced security through environment isolation.
- Reduced risk of misconfigurations affecting production.
- Ability to customize rules and settings per environment based on different needs.
- Easier compliance with certain regulations that may require separation.

The decision between a shared versus separate Azure Firewall setup should be as per your organization's operational and compliance needs.

References:

- [What are the Azure Firewall Manager architecture options?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/firewall-manager/vhubs-and-vnets#what-are-the-azure-firewall-manager-architecture-options)
- [Hub-and-spoke network topology](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-adoption-framework/ready/azure-best-practices/hub-spoke-network-topology#overview)
- [Azure DDoS Protection reference architectures](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-reference-architectures#hub-and-spoke-network-topology-with-azure-firewall-and-azure-bastion)